# Event Handler Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I'm using http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/wp7-looping-selector/ as a timer selector

It has an even handler for example

```
hours.DataSource.SelectionChanged += //not sure what to put here
```

I'm not sure what to put after the += and I don't know where the whole code block should be placed in my WP7 app?

I want a button to be enabled when the selector is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
hours.DataSource.SelectionChanged += 
      new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(DataSource_SelectionChanged);
```

Then create the method like this:

```
void DataSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code here!
}
```

Comment: That is what I came up with. but where in my application do I put this so that it will run when ever the selection is changed?

Comment: @Chris I'd wire it up immediately after you set the datasource. Presumably in the Loaded event of the appropriate page or in whatever method you use to set the datasource.